# Problema al pasar datos a un componente del cliente desde page.tsx del servidor nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

NEXT JS 13. Tengo problemas en pasar unos datos asincronos como parametro a otro componente que esta del lado del cliente. Especificamente, cuando hago console.log(userId) dentro de ListCard.jsx, en la consola del navegador aparece como undefined a pesar de que cuando hago el mismo comando dentro de page.jsx (Del lado del servidor) no tengo ningun problema y devuelve un Int. esto me afecta por que tengo en ListCard un renderizado condicional, es decir el  solo aparece si el user.id== lista.useriD es decir si el usuario logeado es dueño de la lista. (pues tengo dos categorias de listas de tareas, una propias y otras que le han compartido al usuario). el problema es que para todos las listas, el boton no aparece, intuyo porque en todas el usuario que paso como parametro esta indefinido.
Que fue lo que intente:
lei que si quiero pasar este tipo de datos necesito serializarlos con JSON.stringfy() no estoy muy seguro si lo hice bien, pero tampoco me esta dando resultados. Pense en getServerSideProps pero lei que ya no funcion en nextjs13. ¿como podria asegurarme que userFound se carge antes de renderizar ListCard? ?¿o esta pasando algo mas con mi codigo?

Adjunto codigo:

page.jsx:

```
async function HomePage() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  const userFound = await findUser();
  const listas = await loadListas();
  const sharedLists = await loadSharedLists();

  return (
    <>
      <section className="container mx-auto">
        {session.user && (
          <h1 className="font-bold text-4xl mt-5">
            Bienvenido, {session.user.name}!
          </h1>
        )}
        <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl mt-8">Listas de tareas:</h2>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 mt-10">
          {listas.map((lista) => (
            <ListCard lista={lista} key={lista.id}></ListCard>
          ))}
        </div>

        <button className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 mt-7 rounded">
          <Link href="/listas/new">Crear nueva lista</Link>
        </button>
      </section>

      {sharedLists && (
        <section className="container mx-auto">
          <h2 className="font-bold text-slate-200 text-4xl mt-4">
            Listas compartidas
          </h2>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-3 mt-10">
            {sharedLists.map((lista) => (
              <ListCard
                lista={lista}
                userId={JSON.stringify(userFound).id}
                key={lista.id}
              ></ListCard>
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

ListCard.jsx:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function ListCard({ lista, userId }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className="container ">
      <div
        className="bf-slate-900 p-3 border hover:bg-slate-800
        hover:cursor-pointer"
        onClick={() => {
          router.push(`/listas/edit/${lista.id}`);
        }}
      >
        <h1 className="font-bold text-2xl mb-2">{lista.nombre}</h1>
      </div>

      {userId == lista.userId && (
        <button
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-2 rounded"
          onClick={() => {
            router.push(`/listas/share/${lista.id}`);
          }}
        >
          Share
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ya intentaste pasar `params` desde el componente server al componente client?

Comment: No estaría entendiendo. Page.jsx no hay params pues no es está en una ruta dinámica. Mi problema es con el user

Comment: Esto parece invalido `JSON.stringify(userFound).id`, puede que `JSON.stringify(userFound.id)` funcione, pero ahi estarías pasando `userId` como tipo `string` a `CardList`, en la lógica del boton, sugiero revisar que tipo de dato esperas que sea `userId` y `lista.userId`,

Answer (score 0):

Yo revisaría la variable `userFound` si ya es un objeto no es necesario pasarla por el JSON.stringify(), esa función convierte un objeto en una cadena de caracteres

```
JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }) -> '{"x":5,"y":6}' // notense las comas sencillas describiendo el inicio del string
```

entonces estás intentando acceder a la propiedad `.id` de un string lo cual en este contexto no es válido.

En caso de que userFound fuera un string que representa un JSON la función que necesitarías sería `JSON.parse()`